Coefficients of invertible element in polynomial rings
Let $f = \sum_{i=0}^n f_i x^i$ - an element of $R[x]$, where $R$ is a commutative ring. I want to prove that if $f$ is invertible if and only if $f_0$ is invertible and the rest of the coefficients $f_1, \ldots, f_n$ are nilpotent.
It's easy to prove that $f_0$ should be invertible. We consider $e = \sum_{i=0}^n e_i x^i$ such that $fe = 1$. Then we obtain following equations
$$
f_0 e_0 = 1, \quad f_0 e_1 + f_1 e_0 = 0, \quad, \ldots, \quad \sum_{i=0}^n f_i e_{k-i} = 0.
$$
Hence $f_0$ is invertible. But how to proof from there that $f_i^k = 0$ $(i \ge 1)$ for some $k$?

"...if and only then $f_0$ and..." You have left out something there. Perhaps you meant "... if and only if $f_0$ is invertible and ..."

@ThomasAndrews Yes, of course. I fixed in my post.

Note, since you are in $R[[x]],$ $e$ might well be an infinite power series. But even if this question is confined to $R[x],$ there is no reason that $e$ should have the same degree as $f.$

This is not true. $f$ is invertible iff $f_0$ is invertible. Intuitively, $f = f_0(1+\cdots)$ and $\frac{1}{1+\cdots}$ can be expressed as a power series. In the case of $R=\mathbb R$, we do have $(1-x)^{-1}=1+x+\cdots$ and the coefficients $\pm 1$ are not nilpotents.

@ThomasAndrews Yes, it is a $R[x]$

@Justauser Yes that's it. Thank you.

@Irene Also the title no longer matches the content of the modified question.
